# I'm having trouble merging changes in Visual Studio; it keeps erasing my files

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, winmerge

I'm trying to merge two git branches in Visual Studio. I have some files that say "added in both", and when I open them I get WinMerge popping up because that's what I have configured for merging. WinMerge says the files are identical, so I hit save. Then I get back to Visual Studio and it asks me if I want to keep the changes I made in WinMerge. I click "yes", and then... if I open up the file I just merged, it's blank! What's going on? I don't know if this is a bug in Visual Studio or in git or in WinMerge but it's driving me crazy... I have to hunt down the previous version of the file and paste it back in...

Comment: Without any proof, I would suggest that this is not a bug in git.  Git is very complicated and integration with third party tools is never 100%.  My suggestion is to do as I do which is only use the visual studio integration to LOOK at history and the like and not use it to actually manage your commits.  Source is too precious to trust a third party integration to manage.

Comment: What command are you using to try and merge the branches? If you're looking for a good GUI program for Git, SourceTree is a good option. I personally just delete or modify the files directly in my IDE with no extra tools. Without seeing the merge conflict, it's hard to tell how to handle it. If you want, you can make a pull request trying to merge both branches on GitHub so we can see the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is with WinMerge, or maybe with Visual Studio's integration with third party merge apps, because switching Visual Studio to use its own internal merge tool appears to have solved this.